# Google hasn’t verified this app - but I'm just sharing code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am a beginning coder, and I am sure I am missing some important knowledge here. I appreciate anyone trying to help me despite my relative ignorance.

I am sharing a google script I wrote by simply sharing the code and showing people how to paste it into the script editor (attached to a Google Form, in this case). When they try to run it they get the following scary warning:

Google hasn’t verified this app
The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account. Until the developer ([user email address]) verifies this app with Google, you shouldn't use it.

I'm not sure why it's being treated differently than if they just wrote the code themselves. All it does is print out the submission in a PDF. It uses these scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
```

Do I have to verify this as an app? That seems like overkill for just wanted to share a script with someone which they just run in their own account...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why it's being treated differently than if they just wrote the code themselves.

It's not being treated differently. If they wrote code that uses [sensitive scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/sensitive-scope-verification) like `auth.drive`, the same warning will show up. However, this doesn't usually show up for paid domain workspace Google accounts.

Comment: But I wrote this code and when I ran it, it asked me to review permissions and authorize - but no warning about an unsafe app. That's what I was expecting for others who are pasting this code into their editors as well. Is there something I can do to achieve that result? Or do I need to go through this app verification process, which I fear is beyond me?

Comment: @Raffi Are your sure it didn't show permission about unsafe app. If you could remove Drive permission, it might go away.

Comment: I am very sure I never saw that warning myself when I coded it. I need the Drive permission because it saves the PDF of the form submission to the user's Drive.

Comment: @Raffi 1. I think it is possible to create a file using just `DriveApp.createFile()` with permission `auth.drive.file`.  2.Did you manually change the scopes in your own project?

Comment: 1. I am using DocumentApp.create(). Is that no good? (I think I need to do that in order to then open the file and write to it, no?) 2. I'm afraid I don't know what this means. I use ScriptApp, DocumentApp, DriveApp... but I'm not sure what it means to manually change them? (Thanks very much for your help and patience. I'd love to learn the ropes of this better, not even sure where to look.)

Comment: look inside your `appsscript.json` file.  If it's not showing up in your file list then go to project settings to turn it on.   You will see a section call oAuthScopes.  You can edit that manual if you wish.

Comment: @Raffi `I am very sure I never saw that warning myself when I coded it.` I am sure I saw that warning myself when I am coding myself, when using sensitive scopes. Could you [clone the project](https://script.new) and see if it comes up?

Comment: Check out https://www.loom.com/share/80d2e7e6e92b4452966ccdf03b44b8cb. It does ask for authorizations, of course. But it does not say "Google hasn’t verified this app" etc.

Comment: @Raffi Maybe it's because you have a paid domain account? Could you try in incognito mode with a consumer account, if you have any?

Comment: The people I'm sharing it with have paid accounts also. At any rate, is there anything I can do about this besides going through the verification process? I'm afraid that is going to be over my head. :-/

Comment: @Raffi Like I said, 1.Reduce the scopes - i) Offer a direct download. ii) Use [tag:google-picker] to let users directly pick a folder, etc.. None of these is easy/straight forward. 2. You may also try publishing as "testing" for up to 100 users https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615 .

Comment: Thanks. I need to learn more. Wish I had the time. This is just a hobby. :-)    Also, you were right - free accounts get the scary warning. Paid ones do not.